# Run Single Test for Lightning Web Component

Tags: unit-test, lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I feel like this is a stupid question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

Is there a way to run a single test file for a single Lightning Web Component.

I essentially want to be able to pass a filename when I run `npm run test:unit` so that only one test runs at a time instead of all my tests.

I have `test:unit` mapped to a script in my package.json file.  Here is a snippet:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "test:unit": "lwc-jest --verbose",
    "test:unit:log": "lwc-jest"
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just pass e. g. a file name after your script name

E. g:

```
npm run test:unit mycomponent.test.js
```

Would all tests matching a file named mycomponent.test.js

Comment: I could have sworn I had tried that already and it didn't work.  Oh well.  Thanks for the quick and simple answer.